# How to use swarm with hyperledger cello

Tags: docker-swarm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello

I try to deploy a `hyperledger fabric blockchain` with 4 peers and `kafka` using a swarm cluster compose of a manager and two worker.

`Hyperledger Cello` seems to be very use to do it but I have the following error. I already managed to use `Cello` with `docker`.

================================================================

```
dashboard          | [2018-01-31 17:31:39,805] DEBUG [agent.docker.cluster] [cluster.py:53               create()] - Start compose project with name=8bd9ae79f329426b9b803eee84df697b

dashboard          | [2018-01-31 17:31:39,805] DEBUG [agent.docker.docker_swarm] [docker_swarm.py:415           compose_up()] - Compose start: name=8bd9ae79f329426b9b803eee84df697b, host=Swarm_deploy, mapped_port={'peer1_org1_grpc': 7350, 'peer1_org2_event': 7650, 'peer0_org1_grpc': 7150, 'orderer': 8050, 'dashboard': 8150, 'peer0_org2_event': 7450, 'ca_org2_ecap': 7950, 'ca_org1_ecap': 7850, 'peer1_org1_event': 7250, 'peer0_org2_grpc': 7550, 'peer1_org2_grpc': 7750, 'peer0_org1_event': 7050},config={'size': 4, 'network_type': 'fabric-1.0', 'consensus_plugin': 'kafka'}

dashboard          | [2018-01-31 17:31:39,805] DEBUG [agent.docker.docker_swarm] [docker_swarm.py:391     _compose_set_env()] - envs {'COMPOSE_FILE': 'fabric-kafka-4.yaml', 'CLUSTER_LOG_LEVEL': 'DEBUG', 'VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE': 'cello_net_kafka', 'DOCKER_HOST': 'tcp://192.168.73.52:2375', 'CLUSTER_NETWORK': 'cello_net_kafka', 'VM_ENDPOINT': 'tcp://192.168.73.52:2375', 'HLF_VERSION': '1.0.5', 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME': '8bd9ae79f329426b9b803eee84df697b', 'NETWORK_TYPES': 'fabric-1.0', 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_PATH': '/opt/cello/fabric-1.0/local', 'PEER_NETWORKID': '8bd9ae79f329426b9b803eee84df697b'}
dashboard          | [2018-01-31 17:31:39,805] DEBUG 
[agent.docker.docker_swarm] [docker_swarm.py:428           compose_up()] - template path ./agent/docker/_compose_files/fabric-1.0/local
Creating 8bd9ae79f329426b9b803eee84df697b_zookeeper0 ... error

dashboard          | Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.
```

================================================================

Answer (score 2):

cello has an ansible agent which will stand up a brand new system for you. Please find more information here.

https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/tree/master/src/agent/ansible

https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/blob/master/docs/setup_worker_ansible.md

https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/blob/master/docs/setup_worker_ansible_allinone.md